# Chemstyle: redefining schemeref to handle autodeclaration of compounds

Tags: numbering, chemstyle, bpchem

> This is a follow-up question to [Numbering of compounds in the order it appears in the schemes (bpchem or similar)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51907/numbering-of-compounds-in-the-order-it-appears-in-the-schemes-bpchem-or-similar)

I had the same problem of the author of the previous question and I tried the solution proposed by  @Werner: it works almost perfectly. Anyway, there is a minor issue I would like to solve (but most of all I would like to understand why it doesn't work as I expect).

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{bpchem}
\usepackage[tracking=bpchem]{chemstyle}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}% http://ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro
\LetLtxMacro\oldschemeref\schemeref
\DeclareRobustCommand{\schemeref}[2][]{%
\CNlabelnoref{#2}%
\oldschemeref[#1]{#2}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{scheme}
  \schemeref{comp1}
  \schemeref{comp2}
  \schemeref{comp3}
  \includegraphics{scheme1}
\end{scheme}

Compound number \CNref{comp1}, compound number \CNref{comp2}.
\end{document}
```

It's almost the same code as the previos question, there is only a difference: the command `\schemeref` is used here without the optional argument `[TMPX]`. If I add the optional argument (which I don't need since my schemes have the standard label TMP1, TMP2, ecc...) everything works fine: the output pdf has correct compound numbering in the schemes and correct compound referencing in the test. If I drop the option argument the referencing in the text continues to work fine (the command `\CNref` is substituted with the number of the corresponding compound) but the labels TMP1, TMP2, ecc... in the schemes are no more substituted with the expected number! They are left as they are, TMP1, TMP2...

Here an image to clarify: [image: labels not sbustituted]

I was wondering why the redefinition of `\schemeref` doesn't handle properly the empty optional argument... No errors or warnings from Latex.

I am a new italian user of StackEschange, so forgive any mistake I made!

Thank you for any help.

Comment: This won't work: as schemes can float, you _have_ to set up your labelling before the float (outside the scheme).

Comment: Do you mean that I need to declare the compounds out of the floating scheme environment?

Comment: @Rackbox Yes, much the same as citations or any other moving references

Comment: @JosephWright: why? How do you explain the fact that `\schemeref[TMP1]{comp1}` works perfectly while `\schemeref{comp1}` doesn't?

Comment: I don't mean the substitution, I mean the fact that numbering will go wrong as you have the set up inside the float.

Comment: I'm puzzled... Why shouldn't this work? If I use the `\schemeref[TMP1]{comp1}` code everything works fine and referencing is ok! Can you provide an example of what you are saying? Thank you!

Comment: @Rackbox you need to test if `#1` is blank and if it is use `\oldschemeref` *without* optional argument, I guess. Otherwise you're probably telling `\oldschemeref` to replace an empty string instead of the default one…

Comment: @clemens: I agree with you, but I thought that this was impossible to do in practice, because it means something like debugging LaTeX execution... How can I perform this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to test if the optional argument is blank and call `\oldschemeref` *without* optional argument if it is. You can do this in a variety of ways. Manually:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\schemeref}[2][]{%
  \CNlabelnoref{#2}%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \oldschemeref{#2}%
  \else
    \oldschemeref[{#1}]{#2}%
  \fi
}
```

Load `etoolbox` and use `\ifblank`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewrobustcmd{\schemeref}[2][]{%
  \CNlabelnoref{#2}%
  \ifblank{#1}
    {\oldschemeref{#2}}
    {\oldschemeref[{#1}]{#2}}%
}
```

Use `xparse`:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\schemeref}{om}{%
  \CNlabelnoref{#2}%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {\oldschemeref{#2}}
    {\oldschemeref[{#1}]{#2}}%
}
```

Or … any number of other ways.