# {chemstyle package} how to reference the graph number label in the text part?

Tags: cross-referencing, labels, chemstyle

I am using chemstyle or chemescheme package to automatically generate labels of compounds in the scheme. It took me a long time to make it work after I notice that it require --shell-escape to display the .esp file in the pdflatex mode.

However, I get all of the compounds labeled correctly, but how can I reference them in the text part? I tried to use \schemeref{label}, but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Answer solved!

I read from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51907/numbering-of-compounds-in-the-order-it-appears-in-the-schemes-bpchem-or-similar/51914#51914) that the author of chemstyle suggesting to use the combination of chemstyle (for scheme mode) and chemnum. Chemnum can correct the reference of compound label in text.

Chemnum is capable with .eps file TMP1 TMP2 label autonumbering as well. 
Chemstyle is only for the Scheme mode purpose.

If your original chemsytle scheme labeling works, simply replace " \schemeref{label}' with \replacecmpd{label} and for the in-text referencing part, using \cmpd{label} and the number will be correct even for multiple scheme cases.

Here you can find the [chemnum package manu](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/chemnum/chemnum_en.pdf).